# Ping does not work in case of VM or Wireshark log capture open

Tags: virtual-machine, wireshark, ping

Trying to ping from target to Test PC ( windows having Virtual Linux Machine)
Ping works smoothly when:
1. VM ubuntu is not turned off
or
2. Wireshark is not capturing LAN where actual connect is made

This is applicable for IP4 and IP6 ping.

- Here VM is configured for Bridged network (same LAN configured in VM)
  If I disable LAN ( bridged n/w), then ping works from target
- Wireshark if capture lets say WLAN, then ping works from target

I had a suspect on the gateway, subnet but the same setup work in absence of VM + Wireshark

Above things shows if same NIC is used by additional utilities e.g. Wireshark or VM, there are certain communication problem causing ARP or NDP to fail.
I have heard of such congestion failure.

Now I wish to know is this specific behavior of PC, PC configuration (e.g. regedit) or something wrong from the target.

Target is a linux based system.

Error mesaage:
icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: Address unreachable

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with 'promiscous mode' on network card at machine where wireshark is running.

Comment: promiscous was on. I made it off and it work with Wireshark still on. @Andrey, thanks.

Comment: Any hints on why should be the error in case VM is on with bridged adapter.

Comment: Any hints on why should be the error in case VM is on with bridged adapte

Comment: That is probably a bug of ethernet driver. In bridged mode virtual machine requires ethernet card to passthrough all packets, and that is what promiscous mode does. Wireshark wants promiscous mode too, to sniff all packets flying in the network. When they both try to change that setting, probably something gets broken and playing with promiscous mode can be a workaround sometimes.